# Check whether or not directory is in path

Tags: python, directory

I'm trying to write a Python function to accomplish the following: given a path and directory, return True only if directory appears somewhere in path.

For example consider the following example:

```
path = 'Documents/Pictures/random/old/test_image.jpg'
dir = 'random'
```

This should return True, since the directory `random/` occurs somewhere along the path. On the other hand, the following example should return False:

```
path = 'Documents/Pictures/random_pictures/old/test_image.jpg'
dir = 'random`
```

This is because the directory `random/` does not appear in the path, `random_pictures/` does.

Is there a smarter way to do this than simply doing something like this:

```
def is_in_directory(path, dir):
    return '/{0}/'.format(dir) in path
```

Perhaps with an `os` or `os.path` module?

Comment: Note that '/{0}/'.format(dir) in path will fail if dir is the first directory in the path.  In your example this would return false if dir='Documents'

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`os.path.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.split) to get the directory path then split them and check for existence :

```
>>> dir = 'random'
>>> dir in os.path.split(path)[0].split('/')
True
```

And as @LittleQ suggested as a better way you can split your base path with `os.path.sep`

```
>>> dir in os.path.split(path)[0].split(s.path.sep)
True
```

Comment: Use `os.path.sep` as seperator

Answer (score 2):

split using `os.path.sep` [os.path.dirname](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname):

```
from os.path import sep,dirname
def is_in_directory(p, d):
    return d in dirname(p).split(sep)
```

**os.path.dirname(path)¶**

> Return the directory name of pathname path. This is the first element of the pair returned by passing path to the function split().

Comment: how it will handle 'Documents/Pictures/random'? also change `d` for `dir`

Comment: random in `Documents/Pictures/random` could be a file or a folder, you should check that

Comment: @dlavila,  how will it match that?

Comment: you are right, if the folder exist you can use `isdir`, but if not, you have to make some assumptions, +1

Comment: @dlavila, I was looking for dirname, I knew there was a way to just get the directories as a string I just could not remember the name, dirname will get the directories then we just have to split on sep.

Comment: `dirname` is the same as doing `p[:p.rindex(sep)]`, it will remove `random` from  `Documents/Pictures/random` if it's a file or a dir

Comment: @dlavila, true, not sure if the OP is actually checking if the dir is a directory on the file system or spitting on the sep,  you could use `return d in _dir(p).split(sep) and isdir(_dir)` where _dir  is `dirname(p)`